# Brunch - How to avoid caching

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, brunch

I'm using **Nginx** on my server and **Brunch** to build a Backbone/Chaplin app. Brunch builds all js to app.js and all css to app.css. The problem is cashing. Common solution to avoid caching - adding versions to filenames. But I've found no way yet to handle it. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to know how to prevent nginx from caching your js- and css-files? In that case you should rather ask on http://serverfault.com

Comment: And there is no simple way of adding “versions” to filenames in brunch, except of using https://github.com/brunch/appcache-brunch

Comment: This is not off topic... a very valid question!